# Problem with GMM library from sklear.mixture?

Tags: python

I want to run this example about 1D Gaussian Mixture Example: http://www.astroml.org/book_figures/chapter4/fig_GMM_1D.html 
But I have this error all the time:

```
    from sklearn.mixture import GMM
ImportError: cannot import name 'GMM'
```

I tried to replace it by from `sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture`  but the code does not work, they do not have the same functionalities.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The newer versions of scikit-learn don't have that module. From looking at the versions it was deprecated in v 0.18 and removed in v 0.20. Here is the link to the OLD 0.18 module, which is the first instance i could find that shows a deprecation warning. https://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html#sklearn.mixture.GMM if you want  you can install an older version 
`pip install -Iv scikit-learn==0.15`, or if you want to use the newer version, adapt the parameters of your GaussianMixture to reflect their new names (e.g. in GaussianMixture, `max_iter` is the number of iterations, instead of `n_iter`).

Comment: @Ju thank you very much for your help. I try to adapt the code to GaussianMixture. It gives me this error: This GaussianMixture instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.

Comment: While the website hasn't been updated, I posted an issue on the github issue tracker and this is the current code for the example you mentioned (found thanks to github user bsipocz): https://github.com/astroML/astroML_figures/blob/master/book_figures/chapter4/fig_GMM_1D.py The reason you get that error is because you are using the gmm.sample before using gmm.fit. the usual procedure in sklearn for learning a model representation  is that you learn the model from data, rather than hardcoding it.

Answer (score 41):

## sklearn Gaussian Mixture implementation

**Old (outdated, not supported in newer sklearn versions):**

```
from sklearn.mixture import GMM     
model = GMM(n_components=3,covariance_type='full')
```

**New and supported**

```
from sklearn import mixture
model = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=3, covariance_type='full')
```

`n_components` default value is 1, choose what you want.  That's number of mixture components.

Comment: Fix the typo in `modele` ;)

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead

```
    from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture as GMM
    model=GMM(n_components=3,covariance_type='full')
    model.fit(X_iris)
```

This should solve your issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).